# Values are mixing in Telegram bot when 2 users use bot at the same time

Tags: python, bots, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

Problem: when two or more users use bot's this function - imagine if first user's right answer is ex. 30 and second user right answer is 10 , problem is here that if first user give wrong answer then function generate new puzzle (new numbers) and right answer also change for the first user but my code changing right answer for second user also.

i'm using pyTelegramBotApi (Telebot) python library

This is my code:

```
n1 = random.randint(1, 100)
n2 = random.randint(1, 100)

# Generating Random Number For Verifications
def genrate_random():
    global n1, n2
    n1 = random.randint(1, 100)
    n2 = random.randint(1, 100)

# Bot Start Command
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_command(message):
    genrate_random()
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    prove_yourself(chat_id)

def prove_yourself(chat_id):
result = bot.send_message(chat_id, "ℹ️ Prove That You Are A Human!\n\n" + str(n1) + '+' + str(n2) + " = ?")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(result, verifyUser)

def verifyUser(message):
        if int(message.text) != int(n1 + n2):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '❌ Wrong Answer ❌')
            genrate_random()
            prove_yourself(message.chat.id)
        else:
          
            print("next step")
```

Comment: if you don't understand anything please ask me

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that because `n1` and `n2` are globals, every time you call `generate_random` (your function has a typo) you will be changing `n1` and `n2` for all users. So avoid this line:

```
global n1, n2
```

Instead create a dictionary such as that the key of the map is the id of the chat, and the value is a tuple `(n1, n2)` that is generated by your function for each chat id. This way, for each different user (uniquely identified by the chat id), you'll have an entry in the map for `n1` and `n2`. Once the user finishes correctly solving the puzzle, you remove the chat id from the dictionary.